# Evaluate variable to a variable in bash

Tags: bash

I have below bash script

```
declare -a input=('alpha'  'beta'  'gama');
alpha="cow"
beta="goat"
gama="crow"
for i in "${input[@]}"
do
   echo $(eval "echo $i") [this is wrong logic]
done
```

I want that when i iterates over the array it shall print cow,goat crow instead of alpha,beta and gama.
How can i evaluate this some thing like $($i) where $i when evaluates to alpha,it sees it as $alpha and evaluates the same to cow.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

```
echo ${!i}
```

Quoting from [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html):

> If the first character of parameter is an exclamation point (!), it
>   introduces a level of variable indirection. Bash uses the value of the
>   variable formed from the rest of parameter as the name of the
>   variable; this variable is then expanded and that value is used in the
>   rest of the substitution, rather than the value of parameter itself.
>   This is known as indirect expansion. The exceptions to this are the
>   expansions of ${!prefix*} and ${!name[@]} described below. The
>   exclamation point must immediately follow the left brace in order to
>   introduce indirection.

Answer (score 0):

Use an associative array (bash v4.3)

```
declare -A input=( 
    [alpha]=cow 
    [beta]=goat 
    [gamma]=crow 
)

for key in "${!input[@]}"; do 
    echo "$key -> ${input[$key]}"
done
```

```
gamma -> crow
alpha -> cow
beta -> goat
```

Associative arrays don't maintain order of the keys. If that's important, you can keep a separate list of keys:

```
declare -a keys=( alpha beta gamma )
for key in "${keys[@]}"; do echo "$key -> ${input[$key]}"; done
```

```
alpha -> cow
beta -> goat
gamma -> crow
```